# Getting running total/percent from returned JSON

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I'm running a query and getting JSON back with values representing the number of people in a specific group. My data comes back like this:

```
0: Object 
  count: 10
  grp: 1
1: Object 
  count: 20
  grp: 2
2: Object 
  count: 30
  grp: 3
3: Object 
  count: 40
  grp: 4
```

What I want to get is the running total and save in an array, so I'll end up with something like this:

`[[0,10],[1,30],[2,60],[3,100]]`

Here's my start, but not sure what I need to put in my `push`.

```
d1_1 = [];
$.each(data.rows, function(index, value){
d1_1.push(***what goes here?***);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Does this do the trick?

```
var input = [{count:10, grp:1},{count:20,grp:2},{count:30,grp:3},{count:40,grp:4}];
counter = 0;
var d1_1 = [];
jQuery.each(input, function(index, elem) {
counter += elem.count;
d1_1.push([index,counter]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var json = [{count: 10, group: 1},{count: 20, group: 2}, {count: 30, group: 3},{count: 40, group: 4}];
var myJSONArray = [];
var myArray = [];

$.each(json, function(index, value){    
    //Results in [{count: 10, group: 1}, {count: 20, group: 2}, etc]
    var temp = {"count": value.count, "group": value.group};
    myJSONArray.push(temp);
    //console.log(myJSONArray);

    //Results in [10, 1], [20, 2], etc
    myArray.push([value.count, value.group]);
    //console.log(myArray);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/z5davs6h/

If you want to push the index into your array you can do someting like this

```
var json = [{count: 10, group: 1},{count: 20, group: 2}, {count: 30, group: 3},{count: 40, group: 4}];
var myArray = [];

$.each(json, function(index, value){    
    //Results in [0, 10], [1, 20], etc
    myArray.push([index, value.count]);
    //console.log(myArray);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var json = [{count: 10,grp: 1}, {count: 11,grp: 2}],
        result = [],
        temp = [];

    for (var i in json) {
        temp.push(json[i].grp, json[i].count);
        result.push(temp);
        temp = [];
    }
```